# Xamarin Forms - How can i get the value/text of a label in listview (itemtapped)?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

is it possible to get text value of a label?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtXx2.jpg)

for example i tapped the "Dessert" i want to get the specific cat_code value and pass it to a variable which i will use later on

My Codes

**Category.cs**

```
public class Catergory
    {
        public string cat_code { get; set; }
    }
```

**MenuCategories.xaml**

```
<ListView x:Name="MyCategory" ItemSelected="MyCategory_ItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <StackLayout>
                        <Label  x:Name="categoryname" Text="{Binding cat_code}" 
                   Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" />
                    </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

  </ListView>
```

What event should i use here? itemtapped or selecteditem?
and how can i get the value of the cat_code or the text of the label? using those event?

**MenuCategories.xaml.cs**

```
public MenuCategories()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetCategoryAsync();
        }




   public async Task GetCategoryAsync()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://ropenrom24-001-site1.etempurl.com/potangina/final/Restserver/index.php/category/view");

        var cat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Catergory>>(response);

        MyCategory.ItemsSource = cat;

    }



    private void MyCategory_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //what to code? to get value of the selecteditem
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `e.SelectedItem` holds the item that was selected, so the code can simply be:

```
private string selectedItem;

private void MyCategory_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedCategory = e.SelectedItem as Catergory;

    if (selectedCategory != null)
        selectedItem = selectedCategory.cat_code;
}
```